# MySQL Connection Monitor from PHP Application

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I would like to know if there is any kind of tool to monitor the MySQL connections from php  application that shows the connections made and if the connections closed or not.

Goal is to fix the application so that when a connection is opened, it is closed after the job is done.

Any ideas?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: I think he's talking about connection management from within a PHP application, not external monitoring. Probably needs clarification from the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pdo.connections.php) to create your connections, and when they either go out-of-scope or are set to `null` they will be closed automatically.

From the linked manual page (emphasis added):

> Upon successful connection to the database, an instance of the PDO class is returned to your script. **The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object.** To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object. **If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.**

Comment: Yes, I am using PDO. So no need to close the connection explicitly? If it closes automatically, what happens if I want to run multiple SQLs a few mill secs apart? It closes and reopens the connection for every SQL?

Comment: @KevinRave: That depends on whether your multiple queries are using the same PDO object. If so, then you're only using one connection per instance of your application, and it stays open until it goes out of scope or you explicitly close it.